# Flutter make simple gradient shadow

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build a gradient shadow widget as shown below.

[image]

This gradient starts from black and end at white, how can I design this type of widget?

Comment: This can be done with a Container ---> decoration ---> gradient

Comment: @NoobN3rd i don't to have this shadow around container, i need to have only bottom of other widgets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done like this,

```dart
Container(
        height:100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.black, Colors.white],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter
          )
        ),
      ),
```

The result is :
[image]

Are You looking for that result?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        offset: Offset(0, 10),
        blurRadius: 10,
        spreadRadius: 0.5,
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It mainly depends on your use case, for instance, if you want to show shadow you can directly use

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black,
            offset: Offset(0, 1),
            blurRadius: 10,
            spreadRadius: 0.5,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      height: 10,
      width: 100,
    )
  ],
)
```

**Output:**

[image]